# Comparing generated observation from binomial distribution

Tags: r, distributions, binomial-distribution

I am solving this question and I am stuck after few steps, Please help in understanding and proceeding :
  (a) Generate 100 observation from binomial distribution with your choice of n 
   (>1) and p (lies between (0,1)) without using the inbuilt command of any 
   software assuming that you can generate observations from unif(0,1).
(b) Based on the observations generated above, find the relative frequency of 0, 
   1, ..., n and compare with the theoretical pmf of binomial distribution 
   graphically (how well you can represent the comparison in graph depends on 
   you). For finding the theoretical pmf you may use the inbuilt function.

I have generated 100 observation without using any inbuilt function :

```
   n<-10
   p<-0.2
   count <- rep(NA,n)
   for(j in 1:n)
   {a<-runif(100)
   for(i in 1:100){if(a[i]<=p){count[j]=count[j]+1}}}
```

and I know that I can generate theoretical pmf using `dbinom(x,n,p)` cmd but I don't know how to compare both result as asked in part b of the question.

Answer (score 2):

The R code in the question produces a Monte Carlo approximation 
of a 10-sample of B(100,p), which is the opposite of what you seek.

Once you produce a correct sample from B(10,p), you can compare it with the theoretical distribution by goodness-of-fit tests, ncluding a $\chi^2$ test.